# Close popup after x minutes unless there was activity

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, popup

I have a link that when clicked, opens a new window using:

```
var win = window.open(url,....);
```

This window contains a flash game.

I want to close the window after 20 minutes of inactivity.

I know I can create a timeout using:

```
var t = setTimeout("dosomething()", 5000)
```

But how can I figure out if there was activity or not on the popup?

**If the user interacts with the flash, can I get this information still via the dom events?**

I want to avoid the situation of closing the window while they are playing :)

This is in a IE based environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
theInterval = 0;    
function doSomething(){
    do something;
}

function ScheduleDoSomething(){
    theInterval = setInterval(function () {
        doSomething();}, timeToClose);
}

jQuery(document).keydown(function (e) {
    clearInterval(theInterval);scheduleDoSomething();
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a listening event for the `mousemove`, `keypress`, and `click` events and clearing the timer every time the events happen.

```
var t = setTimeout(closeWindow, 5000);
$(document).on('mousemove keypress click', function(){
   clearTimeout(t);
   t = setTimeout(closeWindow, 5000); 
});

function closeWindow(){
   window.close();
}
```

Comment: I have tested this in IE9 and FF 17.0.1 and it appears to be working as expected for me.